# Hadoop FileAlreadyExistsException when creating new SparkContext

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

Even though having run  successfully a spark program a few dozen times, after the latest sbt package the latest run is having a FileAlreadyExistsException upon starting the SparkContext:

> Note: I had run sbt clean package assembly first.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileAlreadyExistsException
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ConfigUtil.addDeprecatedKeys(ConfigUtil.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ConfigUtil.loadResources(ConfigUtil.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.<clinit>(JobConf.java:119)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:1844)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:257)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:749)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:734)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:607)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2154)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2154)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2154)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:301)
        at mllib.perf.TestRunner$.main(TestRunner.scala:27)
  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("TestRunner: " + testName))

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
```

Whatever Hadoop temp and Input/Output directories are being created are within the control of Spark and not performed by user code. So then how to address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error my guess would be you need a clean build package assembly since it isn't even able to find the FileAreadyExists exception.

Comment: I had performed that operation just prior. I will update the OP

Comment: He meant clean also the created directories!

Comment: It can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244860/spark-rdd-method-saveastextfile-throwing-exception-even-after-deleting-the-out